# Was Frodo sad when he heard that Boromir had died?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Is there any evidence to prove that Frodo mourned for Boromir? Did he forgive Boromir for the attack on Amon Hen?

Comment: Seems like *you* maybe did not grieve for Boromir? Like, is your question about "How could Frodo possibly forgive Boromir?"

Answer (score 13):

#### It would be unlike Frodo to express his emotion outwardly.

Frodo remains a very reserved character throughout the books and tends to keep his emotional struggle to himself. Frodo is seen pitying Boromir after he is attacked:

> Terror and grief shook him, seeing in his thought the mad fierce face of Boromir, and his burning eyes.
>   <sub>The Fellowship of the Ring, Book Two, Chapter X: The Breaking of the Fellowship</sub>

Immediately after the attack he grieves for Boromir, at this stage Frodo is aware of the weight of the Ring and its effect. Frodo is aware that the fault lies not with Boromir but the trickery of the Ring.

> This at least is plain: the evil of the Ring is already at work even in the Company, and the Ring must leave them before it does more harm.

Further evidence of Frodo's grief about Boromir is shown in the meeting with Faramir. Frodo considered himself a friend of Boromir, although was unsure if the same could be said of the relationship in return.

> “Were you a friend of Boromir?’
>   Vividly before Frodo’s mind came the memory of Boromir’s assault upon him, and for a moment he hesitated. Faramir’s eyes watching him grew harder. ‘Boromir was a valiant member of our Company,’ said Frodo at length. **‘Yes, I was his friend, for my part.’**
>   Faramir smiled grimly. ‘Then you would grieve to learn that Boromir is dead?’
>   **‘I would grieve indeed,’** said Frodo.
>   <sub>The Two Towers, Book Four, Chapter V: The Window On The West</sub>

As for forgiveness this isn't covered explicitly in *the Lord of the Rings* but given Frodo's grief in hearing of the news and the pity he felt for Boromir, as well as his forgiveness of Sméagol for the evil he committed under the spell of the Ring it seems very unlikely indeed that Frodo hadn't also forgiven Boromir. Especially if and when he learnt of his protection of his friend, Pippin and Merry.

Comment: "Frodo is aware that the fault lies not with Boromir but the trickery of the Ring." would imply that from Frodo's perspective there isn't anything he needs to forgive Boromir for.